# CK Editor add style for a page

Tags: ckeditor, liferay

How could I add a style using CK Editor ?

I want to create a style which I will use it in the `class` attribute on the liferay editor .

For example -

In the page javascript section

```
CKEDITOR.XXXX(// add style class for red color called 'myRed')
```

and then in the editor -

```
<p class="myRed">Text</p>
```

would give red text .

Comment: You have to made an hook extension plugin and alter the ckeditor init file. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7104152/liferay-customize-ckeditor

Answer (score -2):

Place in your theme:

```
.myRed {
   color: red;
}
```

Then only include the class in source mode of the editor like you described in your question:

```
<p class="myRed">Text</p>
```

that's it.

Comment: Wrong response! The question ask how extend ckeditor, not how to have a red paragraph...

Comment: I would recommend that you re-read the question. The Answer given is absolutely the one he is asking for, even though he confused the css part with the JavaScript part of instantiating the editor.